# angular2 test observable guard

Tags: angular, testing

I want to test a guard that returns observable response. Here is my guard code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { UserService, User } from '@app/user';

@Injectable()
export class SignGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private router: Router, private userService: UserService) { }

  canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    return this.userService.get().map((user: User) => {
      if (user.isPremium()) {
        this.router.navigate([state.url, 'success']);
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

And my test code (inject needed services)

```
beforeEach(inject([SignGuard, Router], (guard: SignGuard, r: Router) => {
    signGuard = guard;
    activatedSnapshot = new ActivatedRouteSnapshot();
    router = r;
}));
```

test case

```
it('...', () => {
    const a = signGuard.canActivate(activatedSnapshot, mockSnapshot);
    console.log(a); // Observable
    a.subscribe(...); // Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'true'
})
```

Any ideas?

Comment: How is `signGuard` instantiated? I'm not sure why `true` type was inferred, but if it's only typing issue, you can define the type explicitly, `const a: Observable<boolean>  = ...`.

Comment: it doesn't help. that's what I get from console.log(a)
"Observable{_isScalar: false, source: ScalarObservable{_isScalar: true, value: User{status: ...}, scheduler: null}, operator: MapOperator{project: function (user) { ... }, thisArg: undefined}}"

Comment: "How is signGuard instantiated?" - it's very default usage ({ path: ':type', component: SignComponent, canActivate: [SignGuard] })

Comment: I mean, where `signGuard` variable is assigned. There's no `inject` in your test. Btw, `canActivate` type is a bit flaky. If it is supposed to return an observable, it should be `canActivate(...): Observable<boolean> {...}`.

Comment: Added inject code. Well, actually it can be false also if params are wrong.

Comment: f your code is same as you posted, it can't, it will be an *observable* of false. Injection looks ok.  Try to change it to `canActivate(...): Observable<boolean> {...}` for starters because this is so. But I still have no explanation how it could be inferred to `true`.

Comment: Changed to Observable<boolean>, but no difference. Anyway thanks